# Comparing two javascript object algorithm

Tags: javascript

Super simple example,

```
var beforeList = [{"name": "A"},{"name": "B"},{"name": "C"}]

var updateList = [{"name": "A"},{"name": "B"},{"name": "D"}]
```

I have to compare this two and if there is a missing data, i have to insert `updatelist` data to before List.

So the result I want is,

```
function someLogicHere(beforeList, updateList){
// some logic here
  return afterList(i.e [{"name": "A"},{"name": "B"},{"name": "C"},{"name": "D"}]  in here) 
}
```

Any good or awesome lib or plug-in is OK.

I made by myself with `forEach` but it really is bad.

Comment: post your forEach code.

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#union

Comment: There isn't a magic function that will do this for you, any solution you find will use a looping mechanism of some kind. Post your code and at least then we can help you improve it to something you would be satisfied with

Comment: I don't know how to mark as duplicate, but this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319150/union-of-array-of-objects-in-javascript goes over the same thing.

Oh, and for the record, the library you want is underscore. (http://underscorejs.org). It's pretty magical.

Comment: If those objects ONLY contain the 'name' property, then you can just use underscore's pluck() to get the values (like: _(beforeList).pluck('name'); ) and then do a normal union() which will combine two lists, discarding duplicates

Comment: If the name attribute is unique I suggest you use an object for beforeList instead of an array, with the values of the name attribute as keys.  That will save you having to search through an array for a name in order to update/add it.

Comment: AWESOME! underscore.js was the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
var afterList = beforeList.slice(0); //Clones the array
var elementPresent;

for (var i = 0; i < updateList.length; i++) {
    elementPresent = false;

    for (var j = 0; j < updateList.length; j++) {
        if (updateList[i].name == afterList[j].name){
            elementPresent = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!elementPresent){
        afterList.push({
            "name": updateList[i].name
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is working @Johny? What am I missing? http://jsfiddle.net/4JUqT/

Comment: I updated the solution. Didn't realize at first that these things are objects inside array positions.

Comment: Yeah, thanks what makes me think why the OP set is as valid response without saying anything

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
var afterList = beforeList.slice(0);

// store all values for easy lookup
var lookup = {};
for (var i in beforeList)
    lookup[beforeList[i].name] = true;

// look for values not in updateList & add to beforeList
for (var i in updateList)
{
   if (!lookup[updateList[i].name])
      afterList.push(updateList[i]);      
}
```