# How to get the unique object by comparing two sets of arrays using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following two arrays:

```
var data1=[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "http://192.168.1.165:90/asset/"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "Assigned"
    }


]
var data2=[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "http://192.168.1.165:90/asset/"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "Assigned"
    },
{
        "id": 3,
        "url": "Assigned"
    }

]
```

Result:

```
var unique=[{ {
            "id": 3,
            "url": "Assigned"
        }}]
```

How can I get the unique object from these two arrays ?
I have tried using a `for` loop like this :

```
var unique = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++){
    var found = false;
    for(var j = 0; data1.length; j++){
     if(data2[i].id == data1[j].id){
      found = true;
      break; 
    }
   }
   if(found == false){
   unique.push(array1[i]);
  }
}
```

But wanted to get a solution using functional javascript...

Comment: Not really a solution, but for all things functional javascript, apparently [lodash](https://lodash.com/) is pretty great...never used it myself, but it might be applicable for you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Union of Array of Objects in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319150/union-of-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
var joined = data1.concat(data2);
var temp = [];
joined.forEach(function (x) {
    var objList=joined.filter(function(y){ return y.id == x.id});
    if(objList.length == 1) // if data count of current item in merged array is 1 that's means it belong to only one data source
        temp.push(x);
})

console.log(temp)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m8txhp4o/1/)

Comment: did you checked my fiddle ? @forgottofly

Comment: Yeah,I'm getting 3 objects

Answer (score 1):

**try this:** first get the objects from `data1` which are not in `data2` and remove from `data2` if it is there then `concat` it with `data2`.

```html
<script>
var data1=[
       {
           "id": 1,
           "url": "http://192.168.1.165:90/asset/"
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "url": "Assigned"
       }


   ];
   var data2=[
       {
           "id": 1,
           "url": "http://192.168.1.165:90/asset/"
       },
       {
           "id": 2,
           "url": "Assigned"
       },
   {
           "id": 3,
           "url": "Assigned"
       }

   ];
   
   var arr3 = [];
   for(var i in data1){
      var dup = false;
      for (var j in data2){
       if (data2[j].id == data1[i].id && data2[j].url == data1[i].url) {
             data2.splice(j,1);
          }
      }
      if(dup) arr3.push(arr1[i])
      
   }

   arr3 = arr3.concat(data2);
console.log(arr3);
</script>
```

Comment: @forgottofly the updated answer will give only one record for current data with id=3.

Comment: Thanks very much @Suchit

Answer (score 1):

Edited for resulting the *single* *unique* *object*!

Assuming you have a function:

```
function unique(arr) {
var uni = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
    var rep = -1;
    for(var j=0; j<arr.length; ++j)
        if(arr[i].id == arr[j].id) rep++;
    if (!rep) uni.push(arr[i]);
}
return uni;
```

}

this would work and give you the single unique object:

```
var u = unique(data1.concat(data2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to make an union of the two given arrays and then iterate through `setA` and look for the matching properties and values in `setA` and in `union`. If found, then the index is stored. If there are more than one index, delete all items from `union` whith the indices.

The rest is then the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Complements).

```js
var data1 = [{ "id": 1, "url": "http://192.168.1.165:90/asset/" }, { "id": 2, "url": "Assigned" }],
    data2 = [{ "id": 1, "url": "http://192.168.1.165:90/asset/" }, { "id": 2, "url": "Assigned" }, { "id": 3, "url": "Assigned" }];

function symmetricDifference(setA, setB) {
    var union = setA.concat(setB);
    setA.forEach(function (a) {
        var aK = Object.keys(a),
            indices = [];
        union.forEach(function (u, i) {
            var uK = Object.keys(u);
            aK.length === uK.length && 
            aK.every(function (k) { return a[k] === u[k]; }) &&
            indices.push(i);
        });
        if (indices.length > 1) {
            while (indices.length) {
                union.splice(indices.pop(), 1);
            }
        }
    });
    return union;
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(symmetricDifference(data1, data2), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```